# Timeseries as 2 numpy arrays ('Date' and 'Data') and then extracting 'Data' from a specified 'Date' range?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy, time-series

I would like to ask what the best 'Date' datatype is to use for the following problem:

I am reading timeseries data from an ASCII file and creating two numpy arrays; 1) `date`, 2) `data`. Once created, I would like to extract `data` from a date range specified from a different ASCII file (`start_time`, and `duration` in seconds). These 'Data' would be extracted into another numpy array and written to an output file.

So far I have:

```
import numpy as np

    date = ['2016-07-05  12:00:00.000000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.010000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.020000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.030000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.040000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.050000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.060000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.070000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.080000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.090000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.100000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.110000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.120000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.130000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.140000']        
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

date = np.asarray(date, dtype=np.string_)
data = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.float32)
```

Then in order to extract from the desired date range I have:

```
start_time = '2016-07-05  12:00:00.030000'
duration = 0.10 
a=[]
a=data[(date >= (start_time) & (date <= (start_time + duration))]
```

And then turn 'a' into an array for writing into another file:

```
a=np.asarray(a, dtype='float32')
```

However - just about every kind of dtype or datetime class I have tried for `date` gives me some sort of error (e.g. object has no attribute 
`_getitem_` etc.,) or is not compatible with a list. What format would you use in this scenario? POSIX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pandas for this. there is really good support for time series stuff, [see the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html). You would probably want to use a time series index for more detailed work, here I am using it as a normal column.

Note, your data and date have a different number of rows, I've added a 0 to the data:

```
import pandas as pd

date = ['2016-07-05  12:00:00.000000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.010000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.020000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.030000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.040000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.050000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.060000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.070000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.080000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.090000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.100000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.110000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.120000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.130000',
            '2016-07-05  12:00:00.140000']
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

x = pd.DataFrame({'date':date, 'data':data})
x.date = pd.to_datetime(x.date)
```

We now have a pandas dataframe with two columns, your date in datetime format, and your data.

Using the to_datetime function, we now have a datetime column, and can easily subset:

```
start_time = pd.to_datetime('2016-07-05  12:00:00.030000')
end_time = start_time + pd.DateOffset(seconds = 0.10) #or minutes etc etc

x[(x.date < end_time) & (x.date > start_time)]
```

giving:

```
    data    date
4   4   2016-07-05 12:00:00.040
5   5   2016-07-05 12:00:00.050
6   6   2016-07-05 12:00:00.060
7   7   2016-07-05 12:00:00.070
8   8   2016-07-05 12:00:00.080
9   9   2016-07-05 12:00:00.090
10  10  2016-07-05 12:00:00.100
11  11  2016-07-05 12:00:00.110
12  12  2016-07-05 12:00:00.120
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. To add to this I used: `b=pd.DataFrame._getitem_column(a, 'data')
c=np.asarray(b, dtype='string')` To get the "data" column as an np array

Comment: you can do x.data.values - pandas holds the data as an np.array internally, the .values gets it out.